# Can I enroll to graduate school (PhD) in Germany?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, gpa

I'm finishing Masters degree in Computer Engineering at university of Russia in this year. GPA of my Master diploma is 4.9-4.0 from 5. I have 3 publications in russian scientific journals. However, my bachelor's GPA is 3.5 from 5 and I think it is main problem for enrolling to PhD. My past low level of Bachelor's degree correlated with the lack of interest in Science. At the moment my interest in Science growing more and more, than more I understand in the research. I'm studying some courses on educational platforms such as Coursera and edX for to correct my past mistakes and for increase my scientific outlook.

Do I have any chances for enrolling to PhD in Germany? I don't pretend to top universities.

Answer (score 4):

The formal requirement for enrolling as a PhD student at a German university will typically be to have a Master's degree, potentially with some (modest) grade requirements (on the Master's, the Bachelor wouldn't matter); and to obtain the agreement of a Professor to act as your PhD supervisor. The latter of course is a very individual decision.

Comment: Thus there is no formal requirements for GPA for the bachelor's degree if I have master's degree. Is right?

Comment: Most of the time the only /formal/ requirement is to have a Masters in a somewhat related field. As stated by Arno, you need to find a Prof. interested in having you as a PhD student. It is somewhat more involved for structured PhD programs, but here again you mostly have to convince a Prof to accept you as a student.

Comment: @DanilaSemenov Yes, the grades from the Bachelor's would usually not matter at all for formal admission. As the Russian grade system differs from the German, there would be some leeway in translating anyway.